# How can I get the WebView search bar to navigate as well as search?

Tags: android, navigationbar, searchbar, webviewclient

My app creates a Web browser using WebViewClient like so:

```
    browser_page = findViewById(R.id.browser_page);
    browser_page.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser_page.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.loading_comments), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    .
    .
    .
```

If I enter the URL https://app.opencomments.com/comment/OGqfjp1gKbFsl6bHz8Sk into the search bar, the WebView takes me here:

[image]

instead of here, which is where the Chrome search bar takes me:

[image]

How can I get the WebView to function as both a search bar and navigation bar, like Chrome does? I've already Googled this problem and tried what was suggested on SO, but no luck.

Comment: Never saw a webview with a search bar or a navigation bar.

Comment: @blackapps The search bar is in the middle of the WebView window.

Comment: If it was there i would have seen it dont you think? ;-)

Comment: @blackapps Load the url https://www.google.com and you'll see it.

Comment: Man .. that is googles search bar. Of their website. Its not a search bar of th WebView. Why are you writing such a confusing post?

Comment: @blackapps Maybe because I expect readers to have actually read my question and looked at the screenshots.

Comment: Wrong thoughts. If a reader reads 'the WebView search bar' he has read enough.